# Mule Custom transport import in Mule Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I am using the custom CIFS Transport explained here.
http://forum.mulesoft.org/mulesoft/topics/file_endpoint_using_a_network_share_cifs_with_authentication

Is there a way to import the custom transport into the studio with an Icon (Just like Mule Cloud Connectors)? 
Currently I have added the reference to the POM file and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the CIFS Transport can not be added to the palette of connectors.

Reason: it's a traditional Mule transport and would require specific Eclipse code to appear in Studio, unlike DevKit-built connectors that by default are able to show up in the palette.

Comment: If I use the archetype given by Mule, will I be able to import it in Studio? mvn mule-transport-archetype:create -DtransportId=xxx -DmuleVersion=3.1.1

Comment: Not you won't. The archetype doesn't generate Studio support. You need to use DevKit if you want to create a connector that will show up in Studio's palette.

Comment: Can I use the DevKit to create a custom transport like CIFS? I have tried the DevKit, the structure of classes created by DevKit looks different than of a transport.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to create anything that does not require transactions with DevKit. And yes, the structure of a DevKit connector is drastically different from a traditional transport. They are very different beasts.